# Perl one-liner with single quote

Tags: perl, shell, quoting

I use a Perl one-liner to create an SQL statement, but I am not able to include single quotes.

This is what I want: Take the first field and add quotes to it.

```
echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print $F[0];'
 'a'
```

I tried a few different ways, but it didn't work for me.

1. ```
   echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print qq('$F[0]');'
   [0]
   ```
2. ```
   echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print q('$F[0]');'
   [0]
   ```

Here is another interesting issue.

It is printing a single quote with the print statement, but if I assign a value to the variable and print, it's not working.

```
perl -lwe "print q( i'am );"
 i'am

perl -lwe "$b=q( didn't ); print $b"
```

How can we use single and double quotes in Perl one-liners?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use single quotes alone. You need to escape them correctly using `'\''` This works:

```
$ echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print "'\''$F[0]'\''";'
'a'
```

Comment: @eugene-y yes. Just remove one of them e.g. `echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print "$F[0]'\''";'`

Answer (score 14):

You need to learn how your shell treats quotes.
I would just use the ASCII value for `'`:

```
echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane 'print "$F[0]\047";'
a'
```

`q//` and `qq//` operators can also be useful in one-liners.

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable with the octal value:

```
echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane '$sq="\047"; print "$sq$F[0]$sq";'
```

Also, a slight modification of your attempt #1 would work:

```
echo "a,b" | perl -F',' -lane "print qq{'\$F[0]'};"
```

That uses double quotes for the outer set and escapes the dollar sign to prevent the shell from interpreting it.

Comment: Or `$sq=chr(047);` or `$sq=chr(39);`   (instead of `$sq="\047";`) (?)

Answer (score 1):

Placing the script in double quotes rather than single quotes will allow you to use single quotes inside the script without having to escape or use ANSI sequences to represent the single quote.  This is likely the most effective and easily-readable solution.

Comment: Using double quotes can be more readable if you have about the same or a larger number of single quotes compared to the number of scalars in your code. Since it's 3 characters to escape a `'` inside a single quotes, and only 1 to escape a `$` inside double quotes. If it's the other way around, or if you've already written way too much of a one liner to go back and change it single quotes can be more readable.