# How can I extract a string enclosed in single quotes in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How do I extract abc from 'abc' using a Perl regular expression?

I tried

```
echo "'abc'" | perl -ne 'if(/\'(.*)\'/) {print $1}'
```

but it showed:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: more solutions posted here [perl-one-liner-with-single-quote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106097/perl-one-liner-with-single-quote)

Comment: @jchips12 - I like the solutions with `\047`

Answer (score 7):

This is not a Perl problem; this is a shell problem: you cannot include single quotes into single quotes.

You have to replace each single quote with `'\''` (end of single quotes, escaped single quote, and start of single quotes):

```
echo "'abc'" | perl -ne 'if(/'\''(.*)'\''/) {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Precede your single-quoted Perl code with a dollar sign to direct Bash to use an [alternate quoting method](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) that turns off shell expansion:

```
echo "'abc'" | perl -ne $'if(/\'(.*)\'/) {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the cheap way is not to surround your Perl statement with single quotes themselves:

```
echo "'abc'" | perl -ne "if(/'(.*)'/) {print $1}"
```

Shell escaping has odd rules...

If you really want to do it the "right" way you can end your first single quoted string, put the quote in, and start another one:

```
echo "'abc'" | perl -ne 'if(/'\''(.*)'\''/) {print $1}'
```

Comment: The first solution works only if there is nothing in shell's $1.

Comment: Double quotes should not be used or even mentioned as first recommendation as there's more overlap in shell and Perl syntax than just the `$1` from the question. Backwhacking **any** `$` is error-prone for humans and gets tiresome quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You have a shell quoting problem, not  a Perl problem.

This is a good use for `sed`:

```
echo "'abc'" | sed "s/'//g"
```

Answer (score 2):

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731128) solves the exact problem. For a generalised solution to any quoting problem, use [String::ShellQuote](http://p3rl.org/String::ShellQuote):

```
                $ alias shellquote='perl -E'\''
                    use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote);
                    local $/ = undef;
                    say shell_quote <>;
                '\'''
                $ shellquote
user input →    if(/'(.*)'/) {print $1}␄
perl output →   'if(/'\''(.*)'\''/) {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your single quote with ''':

`echo "'abc'" |  perl -ne 'if( /'\''(.*)'\''/ ){print $1}'`